# In 2 Corinthians 10:8 what is meant by "put to shame"?

Tags: greek, word-study, 2-corinthians

> [2Co 10:7-9 ASV](https://www.blueletterbible.org/asv/2co/10/8/t_bibles_1088008)(7) Ye look at the things that are before your face. If any man trusteth in himself that he is Christ's, let him consider this again with himself, that, even as he is Christ's, so also are we. (8) For though I should glory somewhat abundantly concerning our authority (which the Lord gave for building you up, and not for casting you down), **I shall not be put to shame**: (9) that I may not seem as if I would terrify you by my letters.

What does he mean that he will not "be put to shame"? Is he saying that he won't behave timidly? Or that his weapons won't make his boasting empty? Or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Paul asserts his authority, given him by the Lord. In this place he 'boasts' 'more abundantly, somewhat' [EGNT]. But he makes the point that such forcefulness is not with a view to 'overthrowing' [EGNT] the Corinthian saints, but rather with a view to building them up.

However, one among the Corinthians is suggesting that Paul might be able to write considerable, weighty letters - but when he appears in person he is a weak man. His letters, it is being suggested, are not a true representation of the writer.

So Paul's boasting (a little, 'somewhat') will not turn to shame when he eventually visits. For the suggestion is not true.

Let such a one (the Corinthian making the suggestion) reckon this, that such as Paul (and it is 'we' so it refers to Paul's fellow-ministers, also) such as 'we' are by word in epistles, when absent - so will they be found when present in deed.

So, though he boasts - by epistle - of his authority, he will not thereafter be embarrassed (and thus put to shame) when physically among them, for what he is in written word, so is he in bodily presence.

Comment: A very helpful explanation, and I've learned something new (+1)